Micrometer Observation lowCardinalityKeyValue and highCardinalityKeyValue uses/use cases?
I do understand micrometer observation. And i see that it supports adding  lowCardinalityKeyValue and highCardinalityKeyValue with something like below -
Observation observation = Observation.start("my.operation", registry)
    .contextualName("span name")
    .lowCardinalityKeyValue("this.tag", "will end up as a meter tag and a span tag")
    .highCardinalityKeyValue("but.this.tag", "will end up as a span tag only");

I do understand what these KeyValues mean, but can some one give a real world use case where such distinguishing make more sense.

This article might help by explaining what cardinality means, what difference it makes for metrics and why it is important to distinguish low and high cardinality (with examples): https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/
The official documentation of Micrometer also talks about this (with examples): https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/observation/introduction.html
The javadoc of the Observation class has an example as well.
But here are a few other:

High cardinality

UserId (if you have enough users)
Email address (if you have enough users)
Any type of resource id, e.g.: productId, orderId, etc. (if you have enough of them)
HTTP URL (/users/12345)
Any type of user input or practically unbounded set of data


Low cardinality

Gender of the user
Country where the user lives
Color of the product (Let's say we know the name of 16 colors)
HTTP URL template (/users/{id})
Sanitized/normalized user input that is mapped to a low cardinality set of data



